# preventing page caching using php

Tags: php

1.) Do I have to upload this code to my server? or just paste between it the header tags of my page?

```
<?php
//no  cache headers
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 12012 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
?>
```

2.) How do I call the code? Would it be something like e.g www.mywebsite.com.php? blah blah blah

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

You have to paste that code to your headers in PHP file, before any HTML output.